# How to load Scripts on AJAX requests?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask

I'm trying to make a SPA web.

Apparently if i load content with AJAX on the innerHTML of an element, the `script` tag in the AJAX content won't work.

The problem is that i need to make another AJAX request in the AJAX content.
I can't just use the JavaScript code of the base template because at the initial page loading, where i bind the events to the elements, the AJAX content is not loaded, so no binding.

**STRUCTURE**
Basically what i want to do is this:

*Base Template:* it has a navigation bar that loads AJAX content on a div called `ajaxContent`, the links *Products*, *FAQ* and *About Us* load the respective templates `products.html`... on the div `ajaxContent`.

*Products Template:* This is the products catalog, that has another navigation bar with the category names, it should behave similar to the nav in the base template: loading the AJAX content in a div called `AjaxCatalog`, but i can't make a AJAX request in this template because the `script` tags won't work.

I'm doing this with Flask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown how you are loading the HTML - in fact you've shown no code at all

However, if your AJAX is getting the HTML as a string, you can use the following

```
const loadHtml = (text, dest) => {
    const p = new DOMParser();
    const doc = p.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
    const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    while (doc.body.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(doc.body.firstChild);
    }
    const ret = Promise.all([].map.call(frag.querySelectorAll('script'), script =>
        new Promise(res => {
            const scriptParent = script.parentNode || frag;
            const newScript = document.createElement('script');
            if (script.src) {
                newScript.addEventListener('load', e => {
                    res({src:script.src, loaded: true});
                });
                newScript.addEventListener('error', e => {
                    res({src:script.src, loaded:false});
                });
                newScript.src = script.src;
            } else {
                newScript.textContent = script.textContent;
                res({src:false, loaded:true});
            }
            scriptParent.replaceChild(newScript, script);
        })
    ));
    dest = document.querySelector(dest);
    if (replace) {
        dest.innerHTML = '';
    }
    dest.appendChild(frag);
    return ret;
};
```

usage

```
let yourHTMLtext = '....'; // this would be the result of your AJAX call
loadHTML(yourHTMLtext, '#ajaxContent').then(results => {
    // at this point, all scripts have been loaded, if that's something you need to know
});
```