# Calling external script via fetch api

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

The fetch API, as being told is very powerful for calling JSON or HTML data. Why it is not similarly used to call script tags within any HTML page and execute those script/'s accordingly?
OR 
If it is possible, then how to call functions within < script > tag from external HTML page that was called via Fetch API?

Comment: so, you're loading HTML using fetch, and it includes some script tags ... is that it? if so https://stackoverflow.com/a/52528815/5053002 - amazingly, even the first couple of statements in my answer there apply to you - as you've shown no code at all

Comment: Hi Sachit, I hope Jaromanda's comment gave you some inspiration. If not, it might be worth looking at ways you might be able to make your question clearer by re-wording it a little and possibly providing some code samples. A lot of users can help if they can see what you've tried already.
There is a great help article on writing a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Best of luck, anyhow!

Comment: @JaromandaX: to make up some code for a simple, clear question, just for the sake of "showing some code" has no merit. In fact, it may very well just blur the picture. The problem at hand here is very clear: loading a script via `fetch` is easy. But how to *run* it, too?

Comment: @Sz. I seriously can't understand the point of the your first comment. My first comment pointed the OP to an answer - why do you have such a problem with it?