# Javascript script tag in static html file served from Express does not load properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a React + Express app, in which I would like to serve multiple static websites.

I've followed this article https://medium.com/@justintulk/serving-static-html-into-a-react-component-using-node-express-8cb9fc9194df and I managed to display the website alongside its styles, but the javascript used does not work.

The files are successfully sent from Express to React when requested, but I think the javascript is not loaded properly (e.g. animations do not work, errors such as that there are some functions which are treated as undefined).

The entire flow of serving the static websites is as follows: The React component that displays the static website fetches the html from the website and then the other resources (css, javascript, images) are fetched. The images and styles are properly loaded but the javascript files are not, although the javascript data returned from Express to React is the one expected.

Here I request the data from React, where this.props.path is like '/dashboard/templates/stylesheets/stylesheet.css':

```
    fetch(`${this.props.path}`)
        .then(resp => {
            // fetch returns a readable stream, so translate it into stringified HTML
            return resp.text();
        })
```

Here is my route in Express, that fetches all the resources besides the html from a static website:

```
    app.use('/dashboard/templates', express.static('./server/templates'));
```

The structure in 'server/template' is as follows:

```
    -stylesheets
      -stylesheet.css
    -images
      -image.png
    -javascripts
      -file.js
```

The script tags, the stylesheet links and the images are as such:

```
    <script src="javascripts/file.js"></script>
    <img src="images/image.png" alt="Navbar" />
    <link href="stylesheets/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

Any help or any other idea implementing this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the inner workings of react, but inserting script tags in HTML using javascript doesn't "load", external script, or "parse" or "run" any inline script - not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52528815/5053002) helps

Comment: I am not inserting script tags in HTML using javascript, the script tag is present in the actual HTML file. I fetch the javascript file based on its src and basically inject the code from it in that script tag. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Oh, see, can't see where you do any of that :p `inject the code from it in that script tag` specifically this